# Android activity manager dead

Tags: android

I am using two activities in my project.I am moving from activity1 to activity2 for traversal of my data. After certain times of moves from activity1 to activity2, I am getting the error `ActivityManager` is dead. Kindly tell me the solution of this exception in Android.

```
ActivityManager(60): Process com.example.textApp(pid 719) has died.
```

Comment: Share some code, How you are doing this traversal?

Comment: You app dies, not the ActivityManager